# How to put Text after Animation is running?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I want to make some text appear after an animation like rotating for 2min.

I tried using method like isRunning() in Animator but didn't work.

```
ObjectAnimator object = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ima, "rotation", 1080);
object.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
object.setDuration(1000);
object.setRepeatCount(0);
object.start();

boolean bo = object.isRunning();


while(!bo) {

      Random ran = new Random();
      int count = ran.nextInt(10);
      String str = Integer.toString(count);
      text.setText(str);

      bo = true ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your animation object and add animation listener to it

```html
rotatationAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

**// set your text visisbilty **


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To listen to an ObjectAnimator, just add the following code :

```
object.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
        /*make your text appear*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

    }
});
```

I hope I could have helped you!